# Is there a way to generate a unique identifier value only once (if not set) and cannot be edited by user

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to generate a unique identifier of a specific length and use this value across multiple pods internally. Since the length must be specific, and I'd prefer this to be handled internally rather than be adjustable by a user, I'd prefer to create the unique identifier on install/upgrade (only once if has not been set already) and not be changeable.

I want to use the identifiers internally as part of a naming schema for objects created within a specific deployment. I want to share these objects across other deployments, and need the identifier to determine if a given object belongs to a given deployment.

I was looking into setting a value in Secrets using `randAlphaNum`. Some problems I face with using Secrets are:

1. Related to this issue: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3053
   It looks like the Secret value will be overwritten on upgrade. There is an open PR for a possible fix: https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/5290
   But I don't have the ability to upgrade helm/kubernetes atm
2. Secret value is b64 encoded. I want to pass the value as an environment variable to various pods decoded. It doesn't really matter if the user knows the unique identifier. So, maybe I don't need a Secret? But, again, I don't want the user to be able to edit the value and the value should never change for a given deployment.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may then try to use `ConfigMap` instead. Seems it doesn't change on `helm upgrade`. Then you can use [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) to pass the value from ConfigMap to the pods.